# Calculate cumulative salary including raises

Tags: python

Is there a way to make this more pythonic?

```
def money():
    current_salary = float(input("What is your current salary? "))
    years = int(input("How many years would you like to look ahead? "))
    amount_of_raise = float(input("What is the average percentage raise you think you will get? ")) * 0.01

    for years in range(1, years + 1):
        current_salary += current_salary * amount_of_raise
        print('Looks like you will be making', current_salary,' in ', years,'years.')
money()
```

Answer (score 4):

- As others have noted, you'll probably want to do some error-checking on your inputs, which means writing a helper function to handle your prompts.
- You're writing a program that handles money and using binary floats, which are designed for scientific calculations. You are likely to run into a variety of small calculation errors! Python has a decimal module for calculations involving money. This will also make your input-handling easier.
- Don't reuse "years" as the iterator in the for loop when you already have a variable with that name. It works here, but only by luck.
- Prefer the format() method to straight concatenation. In this case it allows you to easily print your numbers with comma separators.

For example:

```
from decimal import *    

def get_decimal(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            answer = Decimal(input(prompt + " "))
            return answer
        except InvalidOperation:
            print("Please input a number!")

def money():
    current_salary = get_decimal("What is your current salary?")
    years = int(get_decimal("How many years would you like to look ahead?"))
    percent_raise = get_decimal("What is the average percentage raise you think you will get?") * Decimal("0.01")
    for year in range(1, years+1):
        current_salary += percent_raise * current_salary
        line = "Looks like you will be making ${0:,.2f} in {1} years.".format(current_salary, year)
        print(line)
```

Comment: `from <module> import *` is discouraged because it can cause namespace collisions and gives static analyzers a hard time determining where a name originates from. `from decimal import Decimal` is better.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a docstring and split the method to even smaller ones

```
def money():
    """Print Expectations on Salary"""
    salary, delta, perc_raise =  get_user_input()
    expectations = calculate_expectations(salary, delta, perc_raise)
    print_expectations(expectations)

money()
```

And I would store the expectations in a List

```
def calculate_expectations(salary, delta_max, perc_raise):
    """Calculate Expectations on Salary"""
    [salary*(1+perc_raise/100)**delta for delta in range(1, delta_max + 1)]
```

Comment: @codesparcle Thank you for the hint. I've edited my answer and renamed the variable to perc_raise.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could write:

Instead of `print('Looks like you will be making', current_salary,' in ', years,'years.')` you could write `print('Looks like you will be making %d in %d years.') % (current_salary, years)`

Also, and this one is kind of important, you should check the input before converting it to an `int` or `float` (maybe the user goes crazy and throws a string just for the fun of it). You could maybe do that with a `try: ... except:` block.

And just to be nitpicky, what's your position on quotes? Do you use single or you use double?

Comment: Your first point seems to have missed that he's using the variable years in the output. So your suggestions don't seem to make sense there.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Edited.

Comment: Hi Paul, I actually do plan to add in a type check as I'm a fan of error checking I just haven't done that yet.  I just like to write efficient code and make checks along the way.  So regarding the quotes, I don't really have a position.  Even though I say that, if I'm right, to quote within there I would have to use double and single quotes so I am probably more likely to use double and then use single as necessary.  I'm REALLY new to all of this so I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that it would make things more pythonic but here are 2 comments to make things less awkward.

You might want to rename your variable name in `for years in range(1, years + 1):` for something like `for year in range(1, years + 1):`.

It might make sense to use an additional variable to make things slighly clearer in your calculations:

```
def money():
    # TODO : Add error handling on next 3 lines
    current_salary = float(input("What is your current salary? "))
    years = int(input("How many years would you like to look ahead? "))
    amount_of_raise = float(input("What is the average percentage raise you think you will get? "))
    coeff = 1 + amount_of_raise * 0.01

    for year in range(1, years + 1):
        current_salary *= coeff
        print('Looks like you will be making', current_salary,' in ', year,'years.')
money()
```